# discover if a binary data contains Ethereum address in it?

Tags: go-ethereum, addresses, cryptography, public-key, elliptic

Is there a way to guess, with some level of probability , that a 20 byte array is an Ethereum address, besides doing a query against the current StateDB and its history ?

I want to discover hidden addresses in the input for contracts, so , I guess, I would need to (somehow) apply elliptic curve algorithm to this 20 byte array and determine if it looks like part of Ethereum's public key.

Is what I am proposing doable? If so, how would one implement this task ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any sequence of 20 bytes can be used as an Ethereum address, so I don't think you can do anything useful here other than check whether the address has ever had a balance.

Comment: but shouldn't there be some pattern within the data? There can't be an address like this : 0x1111111111111111111111111111111111111111 , or is it? If so, a private key for an address with all zeros must exist too and this address has a lot of money.

Comment: I believe that `0x1111111111111111111111111111111111111111` is exactly as likely as an address as any other. And yes, there very likely exist a private key for `0x0` as well.